# Typescript error: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

This is my current code:

```js
interface sizes {
  [key: string]: Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>[];
}

export const useStyleBlocks = (
  resolution = 'large',
  blocks = [{}]
): Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>[] => {
  const starterBlock = [] as Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>[];
  const handleBlocks = (key: sizes): Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>[] => {
    for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
      // the error comes from this line exactly on [key]
      // A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'
      starterBlock.push({ [key]: blocks });
    }

    return starterBlock;
  };

  switch (resolution) {
    case 'small':
      // then here i get another error
      // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'sizes'
      handleBlocks('small');
      break;
    default:
      handleBlocks({});
      break;
  }

  return starterBlock;
};
```

The explanation about the errors are commented within the code above ^

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

If I change the function `handleBlocks` to:

```js
  const handleBlocks = (key: string): Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>[] => {
    for (let i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
/* HERE I GET A NEW ERROR:
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: {}[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>'.
  Index signatures are incompatible.
    Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345) */
      starterBlock.push({ [key]: blocks });
    }

    return starterBlock;
  };
```

With that change, the error on the `switch` statement is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
const handleBlocks = (key: sizes): Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>[] => {
```

is saying that `handleBlocks` wants an argument of type `sizes`, an interface that  is an object, but when you call `handleBlocks`, you're passing in a string ('small').

Then, it's complaining that you're trying to use an object type for a computed property name, since `key` is of type `sizes`, which is an object.

Comment: So how can I fix it?

Comment: What is your intended result for `handleBlocks`? Right now, you're creating an array which is supposed to be of type `Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>`, which if I understand correctly, is an object made up of string keys and string or null values. But you're building an array of objects with string keys and an object array (`blocks`) as the value, which doesn't match the `Partial<CSSStyleDeclaration>` type.

Comment: Guessing you're intending to use `starterBlock.push({ [key]: blocks[i] });`, but that still puts you putting an object into that value, which doesn't match the type.

Comment: I need to return something like this:`const largeFinal = [{ large: blockStyles1 }, { large: blockStyles2 }];`

Comment: With `blockStyles1` and `blockStyles2` being strings?

Comment: No, this:`const blockStyles1 = {
    ...commonStyles,
    fontSize: '18px',
    fontWeight: '600'
};`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222801/discussion-between-mikethereader-and-non).

Comment: It is a list of JS/CSS styles.